# Compute Expectation of double Ito Integral

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Let $B_t$ be a standard BM and $M_t := \int_0^t e^{B_s} \, dB_s$. The task is to compute the expectation

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}(M_1 M_2).
\end{align*}

Now is it legal to calculate, by using $dM_t = e^{B_t} \, dB_t$, that

\begin{align*}
E(M_1M_2)
&= E \biggl( \int_0^2 \int_0^1 e^{B_t}e^{B_s} \, dB_s dB_t \biggr) \\
&= E \biggl( \int_0^2 \underbrace{\int_0^1 1 \, dM_s}_{\stackrel{d}{=} \mathcal{N}(0,1)} dM_t \biggr)
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} E(XY)
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} E(X) E(Y)
= 0,
\end{align*}

where $X$ and $Y$ are independent standard normal?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

---

There is more or less nothing true in all what you said. You don't have Fubini with Itô integrals. Moreover, it's not clear what are $X$ and $Y$ in your question. Finally, it's not true that $M_1\sim \mathcal N(0,1)$.

---

Let $(\mathcal F_t$) being the natural filtration of $(B_t)$. Using basic properties of Itô-integral yields,

\begin{align*}
\mathbb E\left[\int_0^1e^{B_s}\,\mathrm d B_s\int_0^2e^{B_s}\,\mathrm d B_s\right]&=\mathbb E\left[M_1^2\right]+\mathbb E\left[\int_0^1e^{B_s}\,\mathrm d B_s\mathbb E\left[\int_1^2e^{B_s}\,\mathrm d B_s\mid \mathcal F_1\right]\right]\\
&=\mathbb E[M_1^2]+\mathbb E\left[\int_0^1e^{B_s}\,\mathrm d B_s\right]\mathbb E\left[\int_1^2e^{B_s}\,\mathrm d B_s\right].
\end{align*}

I let you conclude.

Comment: (+1) Nice rendition of an elementary trick! I guess Itô isometry is another way to go.

Comment: Thanks! $ \mathbb{E}(M_1^2) = \frac{1}{2}(e^2-1) $ for the first summand and $\mathbb{E} (M_1) = 0$ for the second since Ito integral w.r.t. to BM is always a Martingale, correct?

Comment: It would be very surprising that you could find a closed form of $$\mathbb E[M_1^2]=\int_0^1\int_{\mathbb R}\frac{\exp\left\{-\frac{x^2}{2s}+2x\right\}}{\sqrt{2\pi s}}\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d s.$$ For the last term of the sum, it's indeed $0$.@KennyfromSouthpark

Comment: Is it wrong to say $\mathbb{E}(M_1^2) = \mathbb{E}( (\int_0^1 e^{B_s} dB_s)^2) = \mathbb{E}(\int_0^1 e^{2B_s}ds)$?

Comment: @KennyfromSouthpark: Yes that's correct (I mean, your formula is true).

Comment: @Surb in you last comment, did you mean that $\mathbb{E}[\int_{0}^{1}e^{2b_s}ds]$ is true or also the numerical value? Because $\mathbb{E}[M_{1}^{2}]=1/2(e^{2}-1)$ is in fact correct

Comment: I mean that $\mathbb E[\int_0^1e^{2B_s}ds]$ is true. It's surprising that the numerical value is true in the sense that Wolfram only gave an approximation, but Wolfram doesn't always give a closed form... so, you need to work a bit more to compute the integral ;-)